# License check is not working

Tags: java, android

I want my app to check license. I used this wrapper: [GitHub](https://github.com/ishida/android-easy-lvl/blob/master/EasyLVL/src/main/java/com/i4da/easylvl/EasyLicenseChecker.java) (with changed BASE64 and SALT)

And when I do check, it always says "Application not licensed".

**What I have done:**
1.Created app draft with alpha testing, and set static test reponse to LICENSED.

2.My Developer Console account is primary account on testing device.